# Unoconv changes commas to dots/periods in numeric fields

Tags: linux

I have converted .xls files to .csv format using the `unoconv` command on Linux. I have noticed that the decimal separator in number columns values are changed from comma (`,`) to dot (`.`).

Command:

```
for input in /test/test_file.xls; do
    unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,0" --stdout $input | tail -n +6
done  > /test/model.csv
```

Input file data (.XLS)

> ```
> killos;water;50,234,00
> killos;oil;83,3
> piloks;gas;72,2
> ```

After conversion (.CSV)

> ```
> killos;water;50.234.00
> killos;oil;83.3
> piloks;gas;72.2
> ```

My worry here, I want to convert data as it is formed .xls to .csv. Is it possible using the above command? Note: Column separator as `;` (Semi-colon). Everything is working fine except this numeric value issue. Highlighted in bold above.